# using system.out.print with java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the below code to map each entry to a print statement, But it shows error. 
Is something wrong in the way I understood [`Stream().map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)? 
How do I use `System.out.println()` within the streams API? how do I correct the following code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("name", "XYX");
    p.setProperty("email", "xyx@mail.com");
    p.setProperty("address", "addr-street-city");

    p.entrySet().stream().map(e ->
            System.out.println(" " + e.getKey().toString() + " " + e.getValue().toString() + ""));
}
```

Comment: You don't map values to print statements, you map values to some other values.

Comment: why does the following in scala 

 " val l: List [Int] = List(1,2,3);
  l.toStream.map(x => print(x))"

prints 1 ?

Comment: I have no experience with Scala, you should consult with someone who does.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use `map`:

```
p.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> " "+e.getKey()+" "+e.getValue())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
p.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue()));
```

or

```
p.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println)
```

`map()` should be used only if you want to alter/modify stream otherwise
for printing to the console `forEach` would do the work as it accepts `BiConsumer` to print key and value

Answer (score 0):

```
properties.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> String.format("%s : %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

- **.map(...)** - convert you `key-value` to a string format
- **.forEach(...)** - prints your string

---

Your output should look like that :

```
address : addr-street-city
email : xyx@mail.com
name : XYX
```